# How to determine the interplanar distance from the Miller Indeces $(h k l)$ of different lattices

Tags: crystals, lattice-model, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

I know that for [cubic unit cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system), there is a simple correspondence between the interplanar distance and the [Miller Indeces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index):

$d=\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2 + l^2}}$

What happens when we have more complex cells (for example, a [rhombohedral cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_crystal_family))? Are these expressions also tabled?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest reciprocal vector is defined as:

$\vec{k}_0 = \frac{2\pi}{d}\hat{n}$

So that $|\vec{k}_0| = \frac{2\pi}{d} \rightarrow d = \frac{2\pi}{|\vec{k}_0|}  $

For a given family of lattice planes you have:

$\vec{k}_0 = h\vec{b}_1 + k\vec{b}_2 + l\vec{b}_3$

with $\vec{b}_i$ the basis of the reciprocal space.

From that you get that
$|\vec{k}_0| = \sqrt{\vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{k}_0}$

If the $\vec{b}_i$ are orthonormal then you get:

$\sqrt{\vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{k}_0} = \sqrt{h^2 + k^2 + l^2}$

If they are orthogonal but not orthonormal you get:

$\sqrt{\vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{k}_0} = \sqrt{(h|b_1|)^2 + (k|b_2|)^2 + (l|b_3|)^2}$

If they are not orthogonal you have to consider the $3×3$ matrix given by $B_{ij} =\vec{b}_i \cdot \vec{b}_j$ which leads you to:

$\sqrt{\vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{k}_0} = \sqrt{B_{ij}c_i c_j}$

With $c_i$ the *i-th* Miller index (summation on $i,j$ implied)